# What's the most efficient way to manage large amounts of data (height data) and replace this huge array?

Tags: c#, .net, multidimensional-array, out-of-memory

I need to be able to look up this data quickly and need access to all of this data. Unfortunately, I also need to conserve memory (several of this will cause `OutofMemoryExceptions`)

```
short[,,] data = new short[8000,8000,2];
```

I have attempted the following:

- tried jagged array - same memory problems
- tried breaking into smaller arrays - still get memory issues
- only resolution is to map this data efficiently using a memory mapped file or is there some other way to do this?

Comment: `new short[8000,8000,2]` is only 256,000,000 bytes. Are you sure there is not some other object in memory that is causing these exceptions?

Comment: you are right - there are other things going on - it just becomes a cumulative problem and this to me seems to be the biggest culprit so I wanted to start here.

Comment: Is the data stored in the array sparse? (i.e. Maybe you don't need to store a value in most of the 256,000,000 locations?).

Answer (score 6):

How about a **database**? After all, they are made for this.

I'd suggest you take a look at some [NoSQL database](http://nosql.mypopescu.com). Depending on your needs, there are also in-memory databases [which obviously could suffer from the same out-of-memory problem] and databases that can be copy deployed or linked to your application.

I wouldn't want to mess with the storage details manually, and memory-mapping files is what some databases (at least MongoDB) are doing internally. So essentially, you'd be rolling your own DB, and writing a database is not trivial -- even if you narrow down the use case.

Redis or Membase sound like suitable alternatives for your problem. As far as I can see, both are able to manage the RAM utilization for you, that is, read data from the disk as needed and cache data in RAM for fast access. Of course, your access patterns will play a role here.

Keep in mind that a lot of effort went into building these DBs. According to Wikipedia, Zynga is using [Membase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Membase) and [Redis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redis_%28data_store%29) is sponsored by VMWare.

Comment: What does such a database buy you? Either you let the database handle the encoding of the data and then the size is probably going to blow up by a fairly large factor depending on how efficient the encoding of the database uses, or you handle the encoding yourself (e.g. by storing parts of the array as a string), and then you could much more easily use a memory mapped file. Actually a memory mapped file would be easier than using a database in any case, memory mapped files are not hard in any way.

Comment: Is that so? The database buys you indexing, allows to store the data persistently, may offer on-the-fly compression, query optimization, intelligent caching and so on. Memory-mapping a file is easy, but doing random reads on a large file is extremely slow and tricky to do right. Let's not talk about inserts should a resize ever be needed. Storing parts of the array as a string seems nonsense to me, *that* would blow up the size and is rather pointless. Why 'encode' binary data, save for endianess?

Comment: Still, a general purpose database is going to be orders of magnitude slower than array indexing. If this data is being processed in (near) real-time, or the processing requires fast access to any element in the array, a database would likely not be desirable.

Comment: If the data doesn't fit into RAM, you don't have a choice in the first place, do you? Also, why should it be "orders of magnitude" slower? Your rusty MySQL on a remote server will be slow compared to RAM access, but an in-memory DB linked to your application will only be marginally slower, yet offering additional features such as caching, prefetching an intelligent memory management and saving you from a lot of tricky issue. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-memory_database

Comment: Okay, then please suggest an in-memory database that can answer a query faster than a single array lookup (or 10 ops or 100 ops).  Don't forget that general databases process structured queries, and just comparing strings involves several array lookups.

Comment: Michael, the OP didn't even say that ultimate performance was a key requirement. Even if that was true: if it doesn't fit into RAM, it doesn't fit into RAM, right? You're trying to tell us that an entire _type_ of database software does not have a right to exist?

Comment: What does "query optimization, caching, and so on" buy you, when you aren't doing queries, and when memory mapped files provide much better caching (done by the operating system). Random reads on a big file are slow, but random reads from a database are much, much slower. You could store the array in a string in a database, because then you get the overhead of the database's encoding one time, instead of for every array entry. Not that I'm not saying that you should use the ASCII representation of the integers, you encode the integers as binary data into a string/blob.

Comment: Ok guys, I give up. Probably the engineers at McObject, Zynga, facebook, Redis, sqlite, etc. (and me) are simply stupid. You must know.

Comment: Why go for a slower solution that's also more work? What advantage does that possibly have? Also, "if it doesn't fit into RAM, it doesn't fit into RAM, right?" is nonsense. If the database encoding is going to blow up his 128MB array to one gigabyte. How are you proposing to store his data into Redis? Are you going to use the built in List type? That would be magnificently stupid as that's going to blow up the data size to *more* than 1GB per array.

Comment: These engineers are not storing a big array of shorts. Since facebook is storing its structured data in a database, obviously an array of shorts is very similar to that and should also be stored in a database, right? Of course not.

Comment: @mnemosyn: No I love databases, and you're right, if it doesn't fit into ram it doesn't fit, but a database doesn't solve every problem.  Even if your database can answer every query in 100us, it would take over 20min to query for each element in the example. That's not very fast. If the data is being run through some numerical analysis, the number of accesses might be far higher.

Comment: @Michael: Agreed. That's where algorithmic optimization comes into play, if possible. But the OP didn't say anything about the algo. Second, one would probably not query each and every number, but batches. Since batches of this data will be incoherent because it is multi-dimensional, you should have something that can query incoherent data reasonably fast. Incoherency is important even if the data *is* in memory, but it becomes tricky if it's not, right?

Comment: @mnemosyn: If you could work with the data in batches, then I would think the OP would never have such a large array in memory already. The example suggests to me that the work to be done with the data requires random (and perhaps repeated) access over the entire dataset.

Comment: mnemosyn, you have still not answered on how you would actually store this data in a database. How are you going to do this so that not both of the following are true: (1) it's slower than using mmap'ed files (2) it's more work than using mmap'ed files.

Comment: performance is the ultimate requirement for this.  I like the suggestion of algorithmic optimization.

Comment: @Darren, you need to tell us a bit about the algorithm then. You should be able to chop up the problem, calculate some intermediate results, and then go on such that at any given time, you need less RAM than available. For micro-optimization, also keep in mind that iterating your multi-dimensional array can produce a lot of cache misses, or very few if done right - again, heavily depending on the algorithm. Also see Joel's article for an example an a more philosophical note: http://bit.ly/8Q3h

Comment: great article by Joel as always.  it really is just a bunch of data, I can see why the person that wrote the code did it that way - its super fast, just not scalable.  I think we'll need to break up the data and only load portions as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need access to all of it all of the time? ...or could you load a portion of it, do your processing then move onto the next?

Could you get away with using mip-mapping or LoD representations if it's just height data? Both of those could allow you to hold lower resolutions until you need to load up specific chunks of the higher resolution data.

How much free memory do you have on your machine? What operating system are you using? Is it 64 bit?

If you're doing memory / processing intensive operations, have you considered implementing those parts in C++ where you have greater control over such things?

It's difficult to help you much further without knowing some more specifics of your system and what your actually doing with your data... ?

Comment: regardless of OS your limit is 700-900MB - you can verify that with a simple test app that allocated a few huge arrays.  I'm not sure I can get away with MIP-Mapping or LOD represenations - this isn't for visualization - its for 2 things - Line of Sight calculations so I need it to be accurate and for checking the mobility of an entity at that location based on the ground type.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend a traditional relational database if you're doing numeric calculations with this data.  I suspect what you're running into here isn't the size of the data itself, but rather a known problem with .NET called [Large Object Heap Fragmentation](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/the-dangers-of-the-large-object-heap/).  If you're running into a problem after allocating these buffers frequently (even though they should be being garbage collected), this is likely your culprit.  Your best solution is to keep as many buffers as you need pre-allocated and re-use them, to prevent the reallocation and subsequent fragmentation.

Comment: Would LOH fragmentation still be an issue for jagged arrays in this case?

Comment: @Michael, According to the linked article, the cut-off for placement into the LOH is ~10,000 elements, so it would depend on how the jagged arrays were structured.  Assuming that you didn't use jagged arrays for the last dimension (would be a waste for only 2 elements), you'd have 8,000 arrays of 16,000 elements each in the given example, which would all be allocated on the LOH.  It could be restructured as 16,000 arrays of 8,000 elements each, which might not be on the LOH.

Comment: Yea it's very close... but I don't think an array of 16,000 shorts would end up in the LOH since it's only 32K.  The 10K element guideline is probably derived from the cost of an 8 byte pointer for each element, and the same article cites an 85K threshold for the LOH.

Answer (score 0):

How are you interacting with this large multi dimensional array? Are you using Recursion? If so, make sure your recursive methods are passing parameters by reference, rather than by value.

On a side note, do you need 100% of this data accessible at the same time? The best way to deal with large volumes of data is usually via a stream, or some kind of reader object. Try to deal with the data in segments. I've got a few processes that deal with Gigs worth of data, and it can process it in a minor amount of memory due to how I'm streaming it in via a SqlDataReader.

TL;DR: look at how you pass data between your function calls O(ref) and maybe use streaming patterns to deal with the data in smaller chunks.

hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

.NET stores shorts as 32-bit values even though they only contain 16 bits. So you could save a factor two by using an array of ints and decoding the int to two shorts yourself using bit operations.

Then you pretty much have the most efficient way of storing such an array. What you can do then is:

1. Use a 64-bit machine. Then you can allocate a lot of memory and the OS will take care of paging the data to disk for you if you run out of RAM (make sure you have a large enough swap file). Then you can use 8 TERAbytes of data (if you have a large enough disk).
2. Read parts of this data from disk as you need them manually using file IO, or using memory mapping.

Comment: Have you actually tried to allocate TERAbytes of data on a reasonable machine in real-life? At a mere 19GB, my machine almost seemed to stop (8GB RAM, 256GB SSD). A naive alloc in one huge array won't even allocate a 1GB array on my machine.

Comment: How are you allocating the 1GB array? I can allocate a 2GB array, which is the limit on .NET. However I can allocate several of them. Note that his array is just 256MB, or by using my advice, 128MB. Of course actually using that memory is going to be much slower than accessing RAM because of course virtual memory doesn't magically give you terabytes of fast RAM, it gives you terabytes of disk storage as if it's RAM. But if the data doesn't fit into memory, what can you do? Using the virtual memory system is going to be faster than going through a database.

Comment: Also, why do you downvote my answer just because I argued that your answer isn't the right way to go, because it's much slower and more work than using the virtual memory system? That's not how stackoverflow should work.

Comment: Again: Have you actually done it? I wrote a couple of memory demanding scientific applications and I know the issues they entail. Your statement is simply misleading - it won't work in most cases. Additionally, if you split up the arrays you'll also have to manage which data resides in which of the arrays. Read about IMDBs and you'll see that these things do have a right to exist and the thing is not as easy as you might think.

Comment: Yes, I have. Actually was working on that just today. I'm actually storing big arrays of floats not shorts, but that's the same problem. Again, how are you allocating your 1GB array? You should be able to allocate that in .NET unless you're doing something wrong (like allocating a 4GB array). I have also used in memory databases. They are good for many things. Storing big arrays is not it, as that is *exactly* the use case of the virtual memory system of the OS, and *not* the use case of a DB. Also, he doesn't have to split up his arrays as his arrays are smaller than 2GB in the first place.